# validate uniqueness of field in scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a user model which has a polymorphic relationship to teachers, students, and admin. These three types of users each belong to a school. I would like to have it so the username of the user is unique within a school. How would I write the validations to accomplish this?

Here is what my models look like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profileable, :polymorphic => true
  delegate :school, :to => :profileable
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  has_one :user, :as => :profileable
  delegate :name, :username, :to => :user
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  has_one :user, :as => :profileable
  delegate :name, :username, :to => :user
end

class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  has_one :user, :as => :profileable
  delegate :name, :username, :to => :user
end
```

Comment: Have you tried the usual `validates_uniqueness_of :username` in your User model? The other classes are only linking there after all.

Comment: Yeah, but that isn't exactly what I am looking for. I want it so the username is unique within a school. So a user at one school could have the same username as the user at a different school.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm quite sure you will need to use a custom validator for this. The delegated attribute will not be usable in the User model. What you could do is also include the `school_id` in the User method and set it using `before_validate` every time. Then you'd be able to use the "simple" uniqueness validator:

```
validates :username, :uniqueness => {:scope => :school_id}
```

However, a custom validator joining the `school_id` of the profileable parent would probably be a cleaner way to go.